# Using angular strap button checkbox with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to the the checkbox example here working http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/buttons#buttons but it doesn't seem to work with the `ng-repeat`.

The radio works fine:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-model="selectedData.locations" bs-radio-group>
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="item in data.locations"><input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</label>
    </div>
```

but the checkbox won't

```
        <div class="btn-group" ng-model="selectedData.checkbox" bs-checkbox-group>
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="item in data.locations"><input type="checkbox" value="{{item.Id}}">{{item.Name}}</label>
    </div>
```

This just gives the "broken angular" indicator with a button and the text {{item.Name}} (including the brackets) rather than a list of buttons.

If I change the `value="{{item.Id}}"` to `value="item.Id"` then it works but it works like a radio button and the model doesn't appear to get updated.

I suspect the problem is in the `value=""` but I can't see why it won't work.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnQ86WDPzo6LrfnvPTD0?p=preview) example of the problem. As you can see the radio works ok, and the last example (from the angular strap examples) works ok but the other don't.
The checkbox3 example has the right behaviour but the model isn't being updated.

Comment: Can you post a http://plnkr.co/ for your example?

Comment: @Leon Gaban - plunker example added

Answer (score 0):

The value for a checkbox is either `true` or `false`. As you are trying to assign the value a numerical ID, you are causing an error. In the plunkr example, the checkbox value is set to `{{button.checkbox.left}}` which evaluates to `true` or `false`

```
$scope.button = {
"toggle": false,
  "checkbox": {
    "left": false,
    "middle": true,
    "right": false
  },
  "radio": 1
};
```

In the HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-model="button.checkbox" bs-checkbox-group>
    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" value="{{button.checkbox.left}}"> Left</label>
```

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/PQvQ2/

Looks like they are wrapping the label in a span, moving the ng-repeat there

Comment: but that's exactly what I had. And it doesn't work (plus there is no such propery as item.value.